# .NET collection with repeating keys and values?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a dictionary type .NET collection supported a repeating keys and values, something like this

```
Collection c = new Collection();
c["Key"] = "value";
c["Key"] = "value";
c["Key1"] = "value1";
```

Dictionary doesn't allow the same keys

Comment: How many items are in your collection when you iterate over it? Two or three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dictionary containing a list:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> MyValues;
```

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest to use the class [`Lookup<TKey,TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx). It acts like a dictionary that allows duplicate keys.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew this class existed. Useful to know when we eventually get NET4 :)

Comment: @Ian, that is not .NET4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @sehe: Even better... unfortunately we're still on NET2 :(

Comment: @Ian : this calss is available since 3.5, enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

If you need something like multimap in C++, there is no direct equivalent in .NET. But you can emulate this by putting a collection as a value into [Dictionary of TKey, TValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> c = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
c["Key"] = new List<string>();
c["Key"].Add("value");
c["Key"].Add("value2");

c["Key2"] = new List<string>();
c["Key2"].Add("Value1");
```

Another way - is to create your own collection that will "hide" all unncesessary operations inside some helper methods. For example, your indexer could check whether you already have apporpriate key in your hashtable and create empty list inside.

Comment: A dictionary does not allow multiple keys.

Comment: Sure, I think many readers didn't understand this question correctly in a first glance.

Comment: @Florian sure a dictionary supports multiple keys. I'm guessing you meant a dictionary doesn't support multiple _values_ per key?

Comment: @Rune FS: Maybe I chose the wrong words. You cannot have a key more than once in a regular dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You´re looking for an Dictionary

Comment: A dictionary does not allow multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx

Comment: A hashtable does not allow multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but why not use the the dictionary but make the value a List?

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> c = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
c["Key"] = new List<string>();
c["Key1"] = new List<string>();
c["Key"].Add("value");
c["Key"].Add("value");
c["Key1"].Add("value1");
```

Comment: Please fix your code. That is a null reference exception waiting to happen.

Comment: Done, sorry guess i was a bit to fast :P

Answer (score 0):

A [multimap](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=321248) should be sufficient.